# Use Gmail spam filters with another email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, spam-prevention

My hotmail account is receiving so many spam emails, the filter isn't working as well as it used to. I have turned it on to Executive so that only those in my contact list can only get through to the inbox, rest goes to spam.

I need some of those who are not in my contact list to get in to my inbox.

I know I can use hotmail with gmail, if I do that will the gmail spam filters work on my hotmail email address?

Answer (score -1):

I've been forwarding mail from GMail to Outlook webmail for some time and nothing that lands in GMail's spam folder is forwarded anywhere.

But if your Hotmail is spammed out, see if you can delete your primary account username after establishing some alias addresses as described below.  If not consider upgrading to Outlook. You can change the username part of your new Outlook address and create alias addresses to foil the spammers.

HOTMAIL:
Hot mail has alias addresses.  If you need to receive mail from, say, old schoolmates or military buddies, post the alias on Facebook or other social media, or your website or other business media.
    If you start getting spam in that alias address, send a new alias to these old friends (or new business clients) and create another alias address to post on Facebook or your website or business media.
    After using those addresses for a while, delete the spammed aliases and the spammers are gone....until the next round.

To set up a new email address alias in Windows Live Hotmail:
Move the mouse cursor over Inbox in the left column in Windows Live Hotmail.
Click the gear that appears to the right of Inbox.
Select Create a Hotmail alias.
Type the desired alias under Email address:.
Click Create an alias.